# a problem about kill user space driver process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Porcess can not respone "kill -9".

Then, if a process uses user space driver, and the hardware may direct access memory(such as ethernet), if the process was "kill -9", kernel will reclaim the process's memory. But the hard ware were still access memory, this behavior may destroy memory data, if the reclaimed memory was alloced to other process.

How to solve the problem about kill -9 use space driver.

Thank you.

Comment: Problems with kill -9 are well known. Implement a graceful exit on some other signal.

Comment: user space driver is exactly like any other user space programs: they may share memory. Shared memory is shared, so it is not removed until all users will free it. It is task for the driver to see if the program detached, and how to handle it (e.g. timeouts). Sharing data is so fundamental that we have many different methods (originated by early fork of Unix)